# Как добавить кнопку на JFileChooser?

Tags: java

Суть такова, можно ли добавить новую кнопку на `JFileChooser` ,если да ,то как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFileChooser это контейнер. Используйте данный код для добавления кнопки в JFileChooser.

```
  JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
  jf.add(new JButton("Button"));
```